# Return count in result with doctrine paginator

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to return the total count along with the results ? 
Currently using this DQL query to get my array results but I also need to return a total count with each result.

```
   $dql = "SELECT a, a.id, a.status, a.departDate, a.flightNum, a.departHour, a.arrivedHour, a.convocHour, a.convocPlace, a.customerPax, a.customerNote, a.providerPax,a.providerNote
    FROM AppBundle:Assistance a GROUP BY a.id";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)
        ->setFirstResult($skip)
        ->setMaxResults($take);
    $paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

    $c = count($paginator);

    dump($paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy());

    return $paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy();
```

Comment: Do you mean return it in the response? You could wrap the paginated results in an object with other metadata such as count, last page etc.. or in the headers

Comment: You can return only one object from function.You need to wrap data in complex object (structure) as @mickadoo mentioned or store count globally.

Comment: Go for https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is possible, to get results and total count in one go, basically under the hood, doctrine perform two queries:

First one to get items:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
// and optional clausules 
WHERE tbl.active = 1 
GROUP BY tbl.type
ORDER BY tbl.rank
// taking one page
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 20
```

second one for count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl
// and optional clousules 
WHERE tbl.active = 1 
GROUP BY tbl.type
```

You can check that in symfony2 profiler.

So you have few options to choose:

Return array or some kind of wrapper object

```
return array("count" => count($paginator), "items" => $paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy());
```

or set it manually for each item if you really need that

```
$count = count($paginator);
$items = $paginator->getIterator()->getArrayCopy();
foreach($items as $item) {
    $item->setCount($count);
}
```

or why don't just return $paginator object?

Comment: Hello , yes this is how I ended up , returning an array. Also removed the paginator since was not really needed. Just wanted a total count for the data grid using this.      count function in repostitory
 
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
        $qb->select('count(t.id)');
 ..
        return $qb
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();

and in controller

    $count = $repository->count(..);
        $asReturn = [
            'assistances' => $assistances,
            'totalCount' => $count
        ];
        return $asReturn;

Comment: NOTE: the reason to use Doctrine Paginator is because it intelligently calculates total even if you've done *ToMany Association Joins. Without that, your total count will include all the cloned rows for every matched join.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle):

```
public function getItemsAction(Request $request)
{
    $itemsQuery = $this->repository->getItems(); 

    $current = $request->get('page', 1);
    $limit = $request->get('limit', 10);

    $pagination = $this->paginator->paginate($itemsQuery, $current, $limit);

    $pagerResult = [
        'count' => $pagination->getTotalItemCount(),
        'items' => $pagination->getItems(),
        'limit' => $pagination->getItemNumberPerPage(),
        'current' => $pagination->getCurrentPageNumber()
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($pagerResult);
}
```